# I get an error when parsing the data. how can i solve?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am pulling information from a URL using `AJAX`.

```js
var settings = {
  "url": ".php",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"email":"mail","userid":"admin","type":"push","apikey":"apikey"}),
};

e.preventDefault();
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  alert(response);
});


$.ajax({
  url: ".php",
  type: "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"email":"mail","userid":"admin","type":"push","apikey":"apikey"}), 
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error.responseText);
  }
```

And then I get data like this using `responseText`. When I print `error.reponseText`, I get data like this:

```
{
  "status": 402,
  "status_message": "Failed",
  "OTP": "536960"
}
```

and this data type is a string. There was no problem when I test it on JSON formatter, but I get errors like (json.Parse anonymous) while parsing it or trying to access error.responseText.OTP

```
var ex = JSON.parse({"status":402,"status_message":"Failed","OTP":"536960"});
```

This is how I trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` works only with string parameter. So you can try:

```js
var ex = JSON.parse(error.responseText)
```

Also, in your code, the URL parameter is `".php"`. What is that supposed to mean? That's probably cause of your error. Try to set the actual `php` filename that you want to send request to.

Comment: I have already tried this and got an error: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0.

Comment: If so, it means, it's already an object. What happens when you try to access `error.responseText.OTP`?

Comment: It says "undefined". But error.responseText contain OTP Field

Comment: Try running this: `console.log(typeof error.responseText);`

Comment: returns string and when i try to parse it get error Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `error.reponseText` has already `Json`, So you can access like this way

```
console.log(error.responseText.OTP);
```

**Updated**

Note that **`JSON.parse()` works only with string parameter**

```js
var str = "{\"status\":402,\"status_message\":\"Failed\",\"OTP\":\"536960\"}";
var ex = JSON.parse(str); 
console.log(ex.OTP);
```

Comment: returns undefinied

Comment: OTP field is not static, so  i need to parse from error.responseText